Mystery of the 50Hz artifact generated with a turned off smart plug and a laptop charger
Here some short background: I am a PhD student doing research in Neuroscience and I am using a 50Hz artifact generated by a laptop charger in my research for the synchronization of different electrical data recording modalities. So I want to start by saying that the aim of this question is not to avoid a 50Hz artifact but to better understand it and to reliably be able to control it.
So in my setup I am using a laptop charger which to my understanding produces a 50Hz artifact by transforming the alternating current from an outlet into direct current suitable for a laptop. Plugging the laptop charger in and out produces a reliable 50Hz artifact I can record and directly see on a screen that looks similar to this:

Furthermore, in my setup I have a smart plug (tapo P110 Voltage AC, 100-240V, 50/60Hz,max load 3680W,16 A) with which I can automatically switch the power on and off which also works e.g. when connecting a lamp.
Moreover I have a normal power strip with a manual switch (250V,50Hz,16.0A, max. 3680 W).
I tested different combinations of those three parts (charger, plug and power strip) and used a multimeter to measure the voltage and observed the following:
For conditions where the smart plug was switched off and connected to the wall outlet and the laptop charger I found unnormal behavior in the 50Hz artifact generated by the laptop charger: When the smart plug was switched off the laptop charger connected to it was still producing a 50Hz artifact which seemed even higher than when the smart plug was switched on. This is something I was really not expecting. It then looks something like this:

Interestingly however, if I did not connect the smart plug directly to the wall outlet but plugged it into the power strip which was connected to the wall outlet, the 50Hz artifact was as expected (very low when the smart plug was off and high when the smart plug is on, see picture 1).
I tried different conditions of the whole setup and also used a multimeter to measure the voltage and the results were as following:
Artifact (50Hz Art.) behavior:

wall outlet-- smart plug -- laptop charger
--> smart plug on: 50Hz Art, off: 50Hz Art
wall outlet --smart plug --power strip (on)-- laptop charger

--> smart plug on: 50Hz Art, off: 50Hz Art.

wall outlet -- smart plug (on)-- power strip-- laptop charger

--> power strip on: 50Hz Art., off: no 50Hz Art

wall outlet -- power strip --smart plug -- (power strip) -- laptop
charger
--> smart plug on: 50Hz Art., off: no 50Hz Art.

wall outlet --power strip -- laptop charger
--> power strip on: 50Hz Art., off: no 50Hz Art.

wall outlet --laptop charger


--> laptop charger plugged in: 50Hz Art., plugged out: no 50Hz Art.
Measured Voltages by multimeter:

wall outlet-- smart plug (off:0-0.001V)
wall outlet--smart plug (off) -- power strip(~950V)
wall outlet --smart plug (on) --power strip (~116V)
wall outlet --smart plug (off)-- power strip (0V) --laptop charger

I hope the explanation is understandable, but I am of course also happy to provide further details. All of this is really a mystery to me and I would be really grateful if someone has an explanation for this strange behavior.
Addition: Here are photos of all the elements in my setup
wall outlet:

power strip:

smart plug:


laptop charger:



First of all, what type of mains plugs you have, are you e.g. in UK where you can only plug in things in one orientation or e.g. in Germany where you can plug in anything you want in any orientation? Also do you have earth connection in your socket, smart plug, and laptop adapter, or is any of the devices without earth connection? Next thing would be to know or determine if your smart plug disconnects both mains wires or just one - in which case you should just mark it as safety hazard and recycle it.

Thank you a lot for this quick reply! I live in the Netherlands and the plugs can be plugged in in any orientation. My power strip does not have any surge protector indication and is generally very simple and cheap so I think it is not grounded. I am rather sure the wall outlet is grounded as it is located in a hospital and should be up to safety standards. It is very hard to find any information about the smart plug from the producer (tapo). Do you have a recommendation or idea how to further investigate its functionality?

Your power strip having a surge protector is irrelevant and unrelated to it being grounded. Please take photos of your mains sockets, plugs and adapters and power strips if you are unable to know if you have Schuko or Europlug in your devices that either pass or bypass earth.

Thanks for still thinking along! And sorry for my confusion and stupid questions. I added pictures to the original post as I am not able to include pictures in the comments.

The smart plugs usually control one line of power. The other line is constantly connected. Maybe that's what causing the problem here. Try to plug the cable the other way (switch the nail position). I'm guessing by using different combinations of devices in between, you are ending up with different power lines to the power adapter and end up with different levels of noise.

Thank you, I did not notice any difference based on which way I plug my cables so far but I will give it a try.

You have grounded sockets/plugs so that's good.
You have Schuko plugs/sockets so basically you can swap live and neutral wires by inserting the plug in different orientation. So basically, you can never guarantee which wire is live and which is neutral after plugging a device in, so both mains wires should be treated with equal care as both may be the live conductor.
The power strip (likely) has a dual pole switch which means it will disconnect both live and neutral no matter which way you plugged the power strip into wall socket.
Then comes the problem. The smart plug teardown videos on Youtube indicate that there are several models but none of them had dual pole relay for mains wires, they all had a single pole relay so it will disconnect only one mains wire, which can be the live or the neutral as you can never know if the plug alwayd passes the neutral or the live and which it disconnects from downstream.
Now, the laptop adapter has likely standard inlet filter caps from live to earth and from neutral to earth, and additionally from live to neutral.
It means that basically live and neutral form a capacitive divider and the capacitive divider output is then basically live at half mains, but it is earthed. As neutral is also at earth potetial, the leakage current on earth wire should be quite small.
Another thing is to where the internal EMI cap connects the USB isolated output to mains side - generally to earth if there is one, but in two-pronged unearthed designs it must go to live or neutral wire.
If it happens that the smart plug disconnects the neutral from your laptop adapter, then you still have a  live wire wigglig at 50 Hz sine wave with 325V amplitude going into the laptop supply, and no neutral, and then there are cap from live to earth, and from live to earth through two caps in series - basically more earth leakage current.
Essentially lack of neutral means everything has 0V potential difference but also compared to earth everything floats at 230VAC.
Also if the EMI Y cap between mains input and USB output side is not to earth but to something that is referenced to live/neutral, it will leak the AC through to the USB.
Also if you plug an ungrounded metal-cased device like a DVD player after the smart plug, I recommend not to touch it and anything else at the same time, or do plugging/unplugging of cables to it. Leaving live going into a device and disconnecting neutral is a hazard you need to be very careful.
Sort of same thing when you change a light bulb, you never know if the single pole switch cuts off neutral or live, and even with the switch off, it's not safe to poke fingers to the lamp contacts.

Thank you a lot for looking into all of that for me and for the very nice and understandable explanation! I will further investigate and test this.

I think that this can be explained by realizing that internally, the laptop charger has a "Y" capacitor from the DC output to the AC input. i.e. to reduce high frequency switching noise on the DC output, the charger's incoming live terminal is used as a high-frequency ground.
This then means that you will see a moderate amount of 50 Hz superimposed on the DC output wires as a common-mode signal. However, if you reversed live and neutral at the AC plug, you might find that the 50 Hz present at the DC port is much reduced.
You can try this if you have a reversible AC plug/socket arrangement.

Hi thanks for the answer! I am sorry to ask but I don't quite understand your explanation. If I understand you correctly on the DC side there should be a 60Hz artifact and on the AC side there is a 50Hz artifact and the noise I am seeing is in fact not a 50Hz but a 60Hz artifact? While that is possible I do not understand yet how this property of the laptop charger is changed by the setup of the experiment, e.g. by using the turned off smart plug versus not using the smart plug? I would really appreciate it if you could add more details as I do not have a good electrical engineering background

@user373724 the 60 Hz bit was an error and, I meant 50 Hz. Fixing in 1 minute. Fixed.

Thanks! Sorry for asking this stupidly but could you still maybe shortly explain to me how this property is influenced by the setup of the experiment in the different conditions? How comes that the setup wall outlet+ power strip+ laptop charger behaves as expected and does not produce a 50Hz artifact when the power strip is turned off but the setup wall outlet+ smart plug+ laptop charger does produce a 50Hz artifact when the smart plug is turned off?  While wall outlet+ power strip(on) + smart plug(off) +laptop charger behaves normally and produces no 50Hz artifact?

It's all to do with which conductors (live, neutral or both) are disengaged when the switches are turned on and off. These are the unknown factors so, get rid of them because they will just defocus you on understanding the problem. Try the charger in the AC socket in one direction then, try it in the other and see what the 50 Hz amplitudes are. If a lot different to each other then my answer is likely correct (seen this many times also).  The set-up of the experiment is preventing you from seeing the reality of the situation AND, that set-up in undefined electrically. Simplify to understand!

Thank you a lot for the explanation! I think I am starting to understand what you mean and I am going to try it out in the next days! However, I am still a bit confused about one thing: when I don't use the laptop charger at all and plug the power strip(on) in the smart plug (off) I can measure a very high voltage (over 800V). If I plug the power strip directly in the wall outlet and measure the voltage in the power strip it is lower (~116V). For me that would indicate that the problem is already there without the laptop charger or do you think another component could have the same problem?
